# Why is the "protect questions" privilege given at 3,500 instead of 3,000 in beta sites?

Tags: discussion, privileges, beta-sites, protected-questions

In [Beta Sites](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), the top privileges go like this:

```
5,000    access to site analytics
4,000    trusted user
3,500   *protect questions
2,000    access to moderator tools
1,500    approve tag wiki edits
```

In [Graduated sites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), it is set at 15,000.

```
25,000   access to site analytics
20,000   trusted user
15,000  *protect questions
10,000   access to moderator tools
5,000    approve tag wiki edits
```

Seeing that Graduated sites consider *protect questions* to be something given in between *access to moderator tools* and *trusted user*, it looks a bit strange that it is closer to *trusted user* in Beta by needing a privilege of 3,500 instead of just 3,000.

Is there any reason for this that I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps beta sites don't attract as many spam answers as the audience is smaller and protecting questions is therefore not needed as much.

Comment: Also, for each privilege, there is a factor of 5x when determining the beta and graduated requirements.

Comment: @Zizouz212 for 3 of the top 4 privileges, the 5x rule works, yes.